# Wireshark Capture Filter Example

Tags: hex, wireshark, ipv6, packet, packet-capture

This is with respect to a Wireshark Packet Capture Filter.

1. IP packets whose IP version is not 4

Solution :

Filter:

```
ip[0] & 0xF0      != 0x40
ip[0] & 1111 0000 != 64
```

Could anyone please provide clarity on how the above solution could be inferred?

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: If my answer worked for you, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If it didn't, add a comment asking for clarification or corrections if needed (I guess you can only comment on your own question as per your current reputation, but no worries I will read it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `IPv4` packet structure:

[image: IPv4 header]

You have the version in the first octet, in the upper nibble. Version for `IPv4` packets is "4" as you can see in the picture, but remember it has to be in the upper nibble, hence the `0x40` in the filter (64 in decimal base).

So what your filter do is grab the first byte of the IP header and ***AND*** it with `0xF0` to be sure it's keeping the version part (upper nibble) and then check if it is different from `0x40` (`IPv4` packet).

What you could also have done is:
`ip[0] & 0xf0 == 0x60`

Which is the same as saying, keep only `IPv6` packets. Version in a `IPv6` packet is equal to 6. The position of the version information is the same as for a `IPv4` header:

[image: IPv6 header]